# Database doesn't show when creating a data source for Performance Point Dashboard Designer

Tags: performancepoint, dashboard-designer

I have a sharepoint server set up, the dashboard runs great, my data sources are great.  I'm trying to add a new data source from a different SSAS machine, and it won't even list it in the database dropdown when I type in my server.

Went thru this with the initial ssas machine and got it to work, and from everything I can see, the new machine is set up the same way.  Is there something I need to set in the cube for it to be visible?  This is an instance of creating a copy of the original cube and hosting it on a new machine.  I type in the name of the server, and where it should list the cubes in the database dropdown, it's empty.  If I change the authentication to Per-user Identity, it tells me it was unable to connect to the machine, verify that the servername is correct and yuo have permission to connect to the server.  I believe Kerberos delegation is set up, I think I'm just missing something simple with the cube.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like a permissions problem.  To verify, you can open your database up to everyone and see if PerformancePoint can connect.  If it sees it now, it should be a simple matter of granting permissions to the correct account.

If this is SharePoint 2010, you need to make sure that the unattended service account used for the PerformancePoint service has permission to the cube.

Answer (score 7):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2012/09/11/specifying-your-adomd-net-data-provider-version.aspx

navigate to \Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\WebServices\PpsMonitoringServer. Open the web.config file. It should be located in the same directory as PerformancePointService.svc. At the very bottom of the file, you should see an  block contained within a  block, like this:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="9.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Change the values in the  element from oldVersion="9.0.0.0" to oldVersion=10.0.0.0" and from newVersion="10.0.0.0" to newVersion="11.0.0.0".