# Why Dashboard Designer In SharePoint 2013 Can Not Load SSAS Database For Create New SSAS Datasource?

Tags: sharepoint, ssas, sharepoint-2013, performancepoint

I use `SharePoint 2013` and `SQL Server 2012 SP1 Update 8`

I Config `Performance Point Service` and `Excel Service` and .... in my `Share Point`.

When I want create a new `SSAS DataSource` in `Performance Point`, List of SSAS Database is empty!

I install `SharePoint` and `SQL Server 2012 SP1`  in the same server.

I Can connect to my `SSAS` in Multidimensional Mode.

[image] :

this is properties of my `Multidimensional Database`

[image]

This Configuration of SSS In SharePoint

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is configuration of Performance Point Service :

[image]

And finally when I want create a new `Data Source` in `Dashboard Designer` , list of database of ssas is empty?!?

[image]

I see this link [Cannot create SSAS Data Source in PPS Dashboard Designer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/48e914ec-b98f-420f-bc12-1e9213a584ec/cannot-create-ssas-data-source-in-pps-dashboard-designer?forum=sharepointadmin) and then i verify and install `ADOMD` in my server and restart my server but until it not work.?!?

Note : I run `Power Pivot Service` and `Excel Services` in my Sharepoint and those services work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fond my problem and fix it .

This is source of answer : [Database doesn't show when creating a data source for Performance Point Dashboard Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199015/database-doesnt-show-when-creating-a-data-source-for-performance-point-dashboar)

As [Krishna N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2888344/krishna-n) say :

I fix it with edit Web.config in this path

```
\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\WebServices\PpsMonitoringServer
```

and in below block :

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient" 
            publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="9.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I change `oldVersion="9.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"` to `oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0"` .

Comment: And if you're running SQL Server 2014 try `newVersion="12.0.0.0"`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was the source of the problem:

The PerformancePoint Services Unattended Service Account is not set. The setting is located in "Manage service applications" in SharePoint Central Administration under the PerformancePoint Services management page.